# Dictionary is showing strange characters when "US English (IPA)" is selected

Tags: snow-leopard, dictionary

I was using the Dictionary application, and I have noticed it was showing the pronunciation using strange characters.

[image: Dictionary screenshot]

I checked the preferences, and they were set to use the American IPA characters.

[image: Dictionary preferences]

Out of curiosity, I changed the option to "US English (Diacritical)"; I then re-typed the same word, and I have got this:

[image: Dictionary screenshot]

It seems that it uses diacritical characters when it should use IPA, and vice versa. Something changed in the last twenty-four hours, as it was working fine, the last time I used it.

I think the problem is one of the preference files used by the Dictionary application. Which file should I restore, to get back the Dictionary application working as it is supposed to do?
Could it be another problem? Which one could be causing this?

Comment: It looks like the "diacritical" setting is working as it should, but the IPA setting is having trouble displaying the non-ASCII IPA characters. The vowel sounds displayed as [ and @ in the IPA transcription should be æ and ɪ, respectively. Do the corrected letters in the last sentence display correctly for you? (The first one should look like an a and e smashed together, and the second one should look like a short uppercase I).

Comment: I see both _æ_ and _ɪ_ correctly, in your comment; so far, I have not have any problems with Unicode characters, except with Dictionary, it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also see `|"br{k@t|` when viewing *bracket* with US English IPA on a local Snow Leopard installation.

But, it is not a problem displaying the IPA characters themselves. Other words that shared those mis-transcribed vowel sounds are displayed correctly:

- *bracket* `|"br{k@t|`
- *brackish* `|ˈbrækɪʃ|`
- *bran* `|bræn|`
- *kit* `|kɪt|`

My guess it that there is just an error in the US English IPA transcription for *bracket*.

Comment: Woah! Yes, you're right; I can confirm br{k@t on a third Snow Leopard install (our secondary computer, which I haven't gotten around to upgrading yet). For what it's worth, brækɪt shows up correctly in Lion. Add one to the feature list, I guess :)

Comment: I see those word pronunciations exactly as you do.