# Where is the IPA pronunciation option in Dictionary?

Tags: macos, monterey, dictionary

In macOS, the Dictionary app used to have an option to [show IPA pronunciation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/18836/5472). I found that useful, since I use multiple languages. Now I can't find the option.

I'm using macOS 12.3.1 Monterey.

Did Apple remove this feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see it on my Mac. You have to change it in preferences, and then look up a word...

[image: Dictionary app preferences]

[image: IPA pronunciation in the dictionary app for the word pronunciation]

Monterey 12.3.1 (21E258)

Comment: Thanks. My issue was that I did not have the "New Oxford American Dictionary" selected. Once I select it in that list, then the option for IPA shows up.

Comment: I don’t see this preference in Ventura.